# PHP XML: how to use createCDataSection() properly

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create an xml dynamically using domDocument.

What I would like to obtain is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
 <book>
   <content>
    <name><![CDATA[dddd]]></name>
   </content>
 </book>
 </books>
```

Unfortunatelly the script below does not show the output as excepted.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$books = $xml->createElement('books');
$xml->appendChild($books);


$book = $xml->createElement('book');
$books->appendChild($book);


$inside = $xml->createElement('content');
$book->appendChild($inside);
 $xml->appendChild($inside)->appendChild($xml->createElement('name'))->appendChild($xml->createCDataSection('dddd'));

echo '<xmp>'.$xml->saveXML().'</xmp>';
```

This is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
 <book>
  <content>
    <name><![CDATA[dddd]]></name>
    <lastname><![CDATA[dddd]]></lastname>
    ....
   </content>
```

I do not know how to use **createCDataSection**().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$books = $xml->createElement('books');
$xml->appendChild($books);

$book = $xml->createElement('book');
$books->appendChild($book);

$content = $xml->createElement('content');
$book->appendChild($content);

$name = $xml->createElement('name');
$content->appendChild($name);

$name->appendChild($xml->createCDataSection('dddd'));

echo '<xmp>'.$xml->saveXML().'</xmp>';
```